# How to use the copy constructor correctly in Java?

Tags: java, oop, copy-constructor

I start learning java after a relatively good experience in embedded C, and I try to apply some simple exercises to ensure the good understanding of java topics,
This is a simple exercise , where I created a copy constructor to make a new object based on an existing one :

```
public class A {
    private int a = 2;
    private int b = 2;
    public A(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public A(A r) {
        r.a=r.a + this.a;
        r.b=r.b + this.b;
    }
    String getDetail() {
        return "{"+a+","+b+"}";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A r = new A(1,1);
        A a = new A(r);
        System.out.println(a.getDetail());
    } 
}
```

And this is what I expect as an output : {3,3}

but this is what I obtained : {2,2}

Could you please explain why ? thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you think `r.a=r.a + this.a;` does?

Comment: This will add the defaut value "2" to "r.a"

Comment: And is it `r` you want to be modified or `a` (the `this` in the constructor)?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a copy constructor is to ultimately copy the same characteristics of an instance specified as an argument to a new object of that class for example:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person (String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Person (Person person) {
        this.name = person.name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

```
Person john = new Person("John", 20);
Person johnDuplicated = new Person(john);
System.out.println(john.name + " " + john.age); //Output: John 20
System.out.println(johnDuplicated.name + " " + johnDuplicated.age); //Output: John 20
```

In your case you have already initialized the instance variables a and b by 2, this will allow for all instances of class A to be assigned with the value 2 by default for the mentioned instance variables. Proceeding to instantiate class A by providing:

```
A r = new A(1, 1);
A a = new A(r);
```

The above will produce {1,1} as output as you are referencing the parameter instance variables rather than the current instance variable (i.e. what the 'this' keyword represents) within the constructor of class A.

In order to allow for your desired behavior modify class A to the following:

```
public A (A r) {
    this.a += r.a;
    this.b += r.b;
}
```

Thus the output shall be:

```
{3,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is wrong, here is solution

```
public A(A r) {
    this.a = r.a + this.a;
    this.b = r.b + this.b;
}
```

But it is not a constructor of copy. Constructor of copy is

```
public A(A r) {
    this.a = r.a;
    this.b = r.b;
}
```

Comment: It's a little weird to reuse `this.a` and `this.b` in the right hand side of these assignments. In fact, the original (initialized) values of `this.a` and `this.b` are always overwritten. It doesn't make sense to keep them. Instead just `this.a = r.a + 2;`.

Comment: Your solution violates DRY. If you want to change '2' constant, your should change it in 2 places. I gave the answer for original question. But I think that constructor of copy should use this.a = r.a and this.b = r.a, and after it `increamentA(2)` and `incrementB(2)` should be called on copied object - this is a best solution, but not the answer for original question.

Comment: Where else is the 2 used?

Comment: 1-st in field initializer `private int a = 2;`, 2-nd in `this.a = r.a + 2`

Comment: Right, that's what I meant in my first comment. That original value in the field initializer is never used. It might as well be `private int a;`.